# Global hotkey called twice

Tags: c#, winapi, registerhotkey

I have encountered a problem with global hotkeys in Windows.
Me and my friend are developing a program (in C#) which is using windows global hotkeys registered via RegisterHotkey function call from User32.dll.

On my computer everything works just fine, but on my friends pc when hotkey is registered it is called ALWAYS twice even if one key press is done and MOD_NOREPEAT flag specified. 
I tried to register two same hotkeys but it is not possible (only one register call for specified hotkey combination is allowed, second same combination is rejected by RegisterHotkey function).

Here is code.
I made a simple wrapper for already registered hotkey (to manage registered combinations from my code):

```
    public class HotkeyStructure
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Id of registered hotkey structure
        /// </summary>
        public int HotkeyId { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Hotkey modifiers (eg SHIFT + ALT etc)
        /// </summary>
        public int HotkeyModifiers { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Virtual key code (all alphanumeric keys)
        /// </summary>
        public int VirtualKeyCode { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Action executed when hotkey detected
        /// </summary>
        public Action OnHotkeyAction { get; set; }


        public HotkeyStructure(Modifiers hotkeyModifiers, VirtualKeyCode virtualKeyCode, int hotkeyId)
        {
            this.HotkeyModifiers = (int)hotkeyModifiers;
            this.VirtualKeyCode = (int)virtualKeyCode;
            this.HotkeyId = hotkeyId;
        }
    }
```

and here is code for class which is managing registered handlers:

```
[Flags]
public enum Modifiers : int
{
    NONE = 0,
    MOD_ALT = 0x0001,
    MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002,
    MOD_NOREPEAT = 0x4000,
    MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004,
    MOD_WIN = 0x0008
}    


public sealed class HotkeyApi
{
    //Constant which detects hotkey message
    private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
    //processhandle pointer
    IntPtr processHandle;
    //process handle object
    private HwndSource source;

    //static list of all registered hotkeys
    private static List<HotkeyStructure> _registeredHotkeys = new List<HotkeyStructure>();

    //external library function import
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr handle, int hotkeyId, int modifiers, int virtualKey);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr handle, int hotkeyId);

    public HotkeyApi(HwndSource source)
    {
        this.processHandle = source.Handle;
        this.source = source;
        //attaching hook to system message sources
        this.source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    //message handler
    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            HotkeyStructure structure = _registeredHotkeys.SingleOrDefault(h => h.HotkeyId == wParam.ToInt32());
            if (structure != null)
            {
                structure.OnHotkeyAction();
            }
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers HotkeyStructure with custom Action passed in parameter (action can be changed during execution via public field in returned HotkeyStructure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hotkeyModifiers">Which key should be pressed with other key to fire an event (option NONE causes disability for selected keycode)</param>
    /// <param name="keycode">Keycode which should be pressed with modifier</param>
    /// <param name="eventHadler">Action which will be fired with registered hotkey</param>
    /// <returns>null if register action failed (eg. registering new hotkey which is the same as one which already exist) otherwise new HotkeyStructure</returns>
    public HotkeyStructure RegisterHotkey(Modifiers hotkeyModifiers, VirtualKeyCode keycode, Action eventHadler)
    {
        int id = _registeredHotkeys.Count + 1;
        bool result = RegisterHotKey(processHandle, id, (int)hotkeyModifiers, (int)keycode);
        if (result)
        {
            HotkeyStructure structure = new HotkeyStructure(hotkeyModifiers, keycode, id);
            structure.OnHotkeyAction = eventHadler;
            _registeredHotkeys.Add(structure);
            return structure;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes hotkey from the list 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hotkeyId">Id of hotkey structure (obj.HotkeyId)</param>
    /// <returns>true if succeeds otherwise false</returns>
    public bool UnregisterHotkey(int hotkeyId)
    {
        if (UnregisterHotKey(processHandle, hotkeyId))
        {
            var str = _registeredHotkeys.SingleOrDefault(h => h.HotkeyId == hotkeyId);
            if (str != null)
            {
                _registeredHotkeys.Remove(str);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }       }
```

and this piece of code is called in App.xaml.cs in OnLoadCompleted method:

```
               var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(App.Current.MainWindow) as HwndSource;
               Hotkeys = new HotkeyApi(source);
```

What can cause this problem?

(Sorry for possible language mistakes.)

Comment: show some code please

Comment: code posted, but I think its not the problem because this works fine on my computer.

Comment: Could it be what you register same hotkey twice for whatever reasons? In any case check for duplicates in `_registeredHotkeys` before adding.

Comment: RegisterHotkey function does not allow to register two identical combinations. For example, when I already have registered CTRL+S and i would try to register another CTRL+S native RegisterHotkey function returns false.

Comment: "processHandle" is a very awkwardly named variable.  It is not a process handle, it is a window handle.  A "process" is a singleton object, a window is not.  In other words, this will go wrong as described if you do this for more than one window.

Comment: Yeah, i know about that about variable name, and I dont know why its still named like that :)
I partially figured out why this works wrong, full answer later.